# iOS NSURLRequest Login Programmatically to a Website

Tags: ios, objective-c, authentication, nsurlrequest, autologin

I was wondering how I can programatically login to a website. I have login credentials. How can I access the website with my login credentials programatically. Note: this is for personal use and the credentials are going to be hard coded.

Comment: A POST request worked perfectly. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on what you want to do. If you are trying to log the user into an actual *web page*, you can use something like the answer I posted on [this question (link)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25001566/automatic-credentials-input-in-uiwebview-ios/25002136#25002136).

However, it sounds like you want to log a user in to a website without them having to go through a web view. In this case, the process will almost certainly require some sort of back-end server. The approach in this case would be to send a secure `POST` request to the server with the login credentials. Then, the server will give you a response (most likely with a *token* that you'll be able to use for future requests to that server).

A quick example of a `POST` request can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3566516/simple-http-post-example-in-objective-c). However, I would ***highly recommend*** using a library such as [**AFNetworking**](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) (what I use), and you should read up more on this process.

Comment: This is for my personal use, so could I just hard code it into the app? I don't want to use a web view (possibly only for logging in if it is easier). Basically, I want the end result to be when I open the app, it will give me my schedule for school, that's it - everything is done in the background on viewDidLoad. I am going to get the schedule from the HTML of the website which needs login credentials.

Comment: Your comment got cut off. If it's for personal use and security isn't a concern, then it'll probably be easier. All depends on what you're logging into and how you prefer to do it. Please accept my answer if it helped you.

Comment: Is there some way I can put the username and password in the text fields if I get the html elements to put them in?

Comment: Yes, I linked it in the second sentence. Here it is again: [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25001566/automatic-credentials-input-in-uiwebview-ios/25002136#25002136)

Comment: Javascript didn't work for me as the button did not have an id and I couldn't seem to find it by its value or class. The POST request did however thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use a block function that includes passing in the `username` and `password` then having a success and a failure block for the response from the service :

```
 +(void)loginUserWithUsername:(NSString *)username 
        password:(NSString *)password 
        successBlock:(void(^)())successBlock 
        loginFailureBlock:(void(^)(NSString *failureReason))loginFailureBlock {
        //evaluate login success via response object or status code
        BOOL isLoginOK = [[responseObject objectForKey:@"LoginOK"] boolValue]|| response.statuscode==200;

    if (isLoginOK)
        successBlock();
    else
        loginFailureBlock([responseObject objectForKey:@"failureReason"]);
}
```

Comment: Looks like what I am looking for, but where do I put this?

Comment: in whatever class you will use to log in